# Error in XML document (2, 2)

Tags: c#, xml

when I am running this program, I am facing this error

```
  public static object Load(Stream stream,Type newType)
        {
      //create s serializer and load the object
     XmlSerializer serializer=new XmlSerializer(newType);
     object newobject =serializer.Deserialize(stream);
      //return the new object 
      return newobject;
         }

?xml version="1.0"?>
-<Address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <FirstName>ali </FirstName> <FamilyName>bradaran</FamilyName> <UserLevel>عادی</UserLevel> <Password>123</Password> </Address>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
-<Address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">                    <FirstName>ali </FirstName>                        <FamilyName>bradaran</FamilyName>                      <UserLevel>عادی</UserLevel>                         <Password>123</Password>                                           </Address>

Comment: codes above is my XMl code that i had it ......

Comment: PLease, read this topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there is an error in the XML document you are trying to read.

Open your XML document in Internet Explorer. If it is valid, it will display. If it is not, the error will be described and shown, which should help you track down the problem.

If the XML you posted is a genuine representation of what you're reading, there is a minus character and two semicolon characters that shouldn't be in the file. I'm also not sure you would want the xmlns attributes in your Address element?

I suggest you search for some XML tutorials on the web so you can get a better understanding of how XML must be formed.